# Would I have to worry about any issues using the Z axis as up/down?

Tags: rust, 3d, coordinates, axis, bevy

For a 3d environment I highly prefer to use X/Y as the landscape with Z as up, are there any issues I would run in to using this convention in Bevy?

Comment: I think this question could more easily be answered if you could specify what you mean with "issues". It would be best if you could give some examples. For example you might need to implement a custom coordinate transformation when importing a gltf file. We obviously can not know if you would consider such things an issue or not...

Comment: Thanks, to clarify: Is there any features of the Bevy game engine that won't work correctly when using Z as up/down? For example the Godot game engine's skybox is set for Y as up/down and does not provide a way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

the main thing that pops into my head is not a technical issue but more that it might get confusing that Transform.forward is in z